# Seaborn Heatmap Subplots - Shared heatbar and heating

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I trying to compare 3 heat-maps. 
I struggle to get the 3 maps to share the "heating" from the colorbar. 
The heating becomes relative to the data set of each subplot, flight, flight1, and flight2. 
And not relative to the different subplots.

Is there a way off connecting the subplots the shared colorbar?

I have used the code below:

```
import seaborn as sns  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
flights1 = flights * 10
flights2 = flights * 2
f,(ax1,ax2,ax3, axcb) = plt.subplots(1,4, 
        gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[1,1,1,0.08]})
ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2,ax3)
g1 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax1)
g1.set_ylabel("")
g1.set_xlabel("")
g2 = sns.heatmap(flights1,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax2)
g2.set_ylabel("")
g2.set_xlabel("")
g2.set_yticks([])
g3 = sns.heatmap(flights2,cmap="YlGnBu",ax=ax3, cbar_ax=axcb)
g3.set_ylabel("")
g3.set_xlabel("")
g3.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

The cod gives this output:

[image: Output from code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the vmin and vmax parameters equal for each heatmap. These are the limits used to calculate the correct color.

All values smaller than vmin will be set to the smallest color, the higher ones to vmax will be set to the highest color. Therefore, if your data has some outliers, you might want to consider bringing vmin and vmax closer together to get more color variation near the center of the values.

```py
vmin = min(min(flights['passengers']), min(flights1['passengers']), min(flights2['passengers']))
vmax = max(max(flights['passengers']), max(flights1['passengers']), max(flights2['passengers']))
g1 = sns.heatmap(flights, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap="YlGnBu", cbar=False, ax=ax1)
g2 = sns.heatmap(flights, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap="YlGnBu", cbar=False, ax=ax2)
g3 = sns.heatmap(flights, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap="YlGnBu", ax=ax3, cbar_ax=axcb)
```